# Get JSON in ASHX AJAX C#

Tags: c#, ajax, json, ashx

Have a script in Home.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function probarAjax() {

    var Publicaciones = {
      "Categoria": "Noticia"
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Controlador.ashx?accion=enviar",
      data: JSON.stringify(Publicaciones),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
      }

    });
  }
</script>
```

Inside of Controlador.ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
  context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";

  var categoria = string.Empty;
  JavaScriptSerializer javaSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  categoria = context.Request["Categoria"];

  var capaSeguridad = new { d = categoria };

  context.Response.Write(javaSerialize.Serialize(capaSeguridad));
}
```

And the result is :

```
Object {d: null}
```

Why this result? if i send a parameter in the data with the variable `Publicaciones` with value `"Noticia"`.

Comment: The solution was this

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function probarAjax() {

        var Publicaciones = {
               "Categoria" : "Noticia"                  
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Controlador.ashx?accion=enviar",
            data: JSON.stringify(Publicaciones),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }


        });
    }    

</script>
```

inside of ashx

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";

        System.IO.Stream body = context.Request.InputStream;
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = context.Request.ContentEncoding;
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);

        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Noticia publicacion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Noticia>(s);
        var capaSeguridad = new { d = publicacion.Categoria };

        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(capaSeguridad));
    }
```

with the class

```
public class Noticia
    {
        public string Categoria { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks for help me

Comment: I get an exception when using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject which returns, "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g.[1,2,3]) into type 'SurplusApp.items' because the type requires a JSON object.

Comment: What would this look if the object contained an array of Publicaciones?

Answer (score 0):

Change: `data: JSON.stringify(Publicaciones),`
For: `data: Publicaciones`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

To your ASHX method.